# List locked. SSIS copy from Sharepoint to SQL Server

Tags: list, lock

I have an SSIS package that copy data from the Sharepoint List to MS SQL table. It work's fine. But yesterday I have an issue that package is getting stuck in validating the data flow. Maybe Sharepoint list is locked? How I can unlock it?

Comment: which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Did someone change your list schema (list fields and/or field types)?

Comment: The problem was with changed fields in the destination table. Now it is solved. Thank you.